# Error trying a manual's example in DB2 11.1.4.4

Tags: db2, json, db2-luw, functions

When trying this example from the DB2 11.1 manual:

```
VALUES (JSON_VALUE('{"id":"987"}', 'strict $.id' RETURNING INTEGER));
```

I get this error:

> SQL0171N  The statement was not processed because the data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in position "1" of routine "SYSIBM.JSON_VALUE" is incorrect. Parameter name: ""

I get the same error for various json functions. Using the Command Line Processor Plus from Windows 10.

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=02dce188639bf7e253b57527eb5b387a). What client are you using to run the statement?

Comment: @mustaccio. Edited

Comment: CLPPlus is weird. My guess would be it's doing funny things to quotes.

Comment: @mustaccio. Also tried from Visual Studio with same error.

Comment: @mustaccio: Server version here is 11.1.4.4. What is yours?

Comment: It's not mine but [it's the same version](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1). You can test yourself at the link.

Comment: Has `db2updv111` been run on your database (if it has been upgraded from an earlier release)?

Comment: @PaulVernon: I don't know. Is there a way to check it from a non admistrator perspective?

Comment: I don't recall.  I think it might update some of the info here `select * from sysibmadm.env_inst_info"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the database must be encoded in UTF-8.

https://developer.ibm.com/articles/sql-json-publishing-functions/

> JSON data consists of a sequence of Unicode characters that are arranged in a hierarchical form based on the JSON value syntax and grammar

Comment: +1 for answering your own question when you found the problem. You should also accept the answers so others easily can see it.