# Error trying a JSON_VALUE example in DB2 11.1.4.4

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'am having a similar problem as described in this question.
[Error trying a manual's example in DB2 11.1.4.4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/error-trying-a-manuals-example-in-db2-11-1-4-4/289779#289779)

DB2 Version: DB2 LUW 11.1.4.4

When running the following sample from the DB2 LUW 11.1 Manual

`VALUES (JSON_VALUE('{"id":"987"}', 'strict $.id' RETURNING INTEGER));`

Im getting the error:

> SQL0171N The statement was not processed because the data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in position "1" of routine "SYSIBM.JSON_VALUE" is incorrect. Parameter name:

Upon checking the Database Code Set is IBM-1252. Supposedly, I should have UTF-8 code set for this to work. I can not change this code-set.

My question is, given my predicament, is there a way to cast so that I can make use of this functionality?

Comment: Hello, i'm in the same situation, did you get any solution?

Comment: Was not able to resolve it. We just created our database in utf-8